# How Do I clear history and cache in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How can I clear the whole firefox history and cache from javascript (using addon's code)?

I think it can be done using places api, but I could not get around it!

EDIT: It cannot be done using places api (see comments). I roamed around and found that XPCOM interface can do it for addons.

If anyone could write a good answer, it would help others. :)

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if Firefox allowed anything that was not the specific user operator to delete browser offline data, why do you think places api can do this?

Comment: @Martin , someone told me. I tinkered around though and found XPCOM interfaces to do so. :) editing the question!

Comment: I don't think that would clear the WHOLE history, more it would/could clear the addon specific history. (?)

Comment: @Martin : I believe `var browserHistory = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-history-service;1"]
                     .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIBrowserHistory);`  and `browserHistory.removeAllPages()` will remove WHOLE history? I think https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIBrowserHistory#removeAllPages%28%29 says that ?

Comment: When you click the "clear history" button in this dialog http://i.imgur.com/LZcADJe.png it calls this function: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/sanitizeDialog.js#9 so it checks if cache is checked and deletes cache, what you are wanting is in this function

Comment: Hi, Noitidart. How can I find what function a firefox button calls? Or a code of a particular firefox window?